# Causes of Back Dimples

Tags: human-biology, human-physiology

What are the causes of the dimples commonly found above the buttocks?  They seem to be in line with the sacroiliac joints.  Do the joints have anything to do with them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Back dimples** or **Dimples of Venus** are created by a short ligament stretching between the posterior superior iliac spine and the skin. They are thought to be genetic.

Source and further reading: [Kumar, Kanojia & Saili (2014) - Skin dimples](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/ijd.12376)

[image: Dimples of Venus]

Comment: @Mesentery, thanks for editing. I took the image of Wikimedia without thinking that it might be deemed NSFW or inappropriate. Thanks again.